# rails memcached cannot load such file -- dalli

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, dalli

I want to use memcached in Rails. 
So I set in my local. Good. and deploy to my server.. a problem comes up

The problem is that dalli cannot be loaded in active_support/cache/mem_cache_store.rb..

My server environment :
 ubuntu / nginx / unicorn / Rails 4 / capistrano 2

**unicorn.log** **(Edit (add log more) )**

```
E, [2014-08-09T10:46:52.306478 #3576] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 25225 exit 1> worker=1
I, [2014-08-09T10:46:52.306772 #3576]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
I, [2014-08-09T10:46:52.315784 #25228]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=25228
I, [2014-08-09T10:46:52.316264 #25228]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
You don't have dalli installed in your application. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install
E, [2014-08-09T10:46:52.377766 #25221] ERROR -- : Could not find cache store adapter for mem_cache_store (cannot load such file -- dalli) (RuntimeError)
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/cache.rb:105:in `rescue in retrieve_store_class'
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/cache.rb:103:in `retrieve_store_class'
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/cache.rb:59:in `lookup_store' 
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:62:in `block in <module:Bootstrap>'
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/releases/20140809040739/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
config.ru:4:in `require'
config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
config.ru:1:in `new'
config.ru:1:in `<main>'
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `eval'
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `block in builder'
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:764:in `call'
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:764:in `build_app!'
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:628:in `init_worker_process'
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:651:in `worker_loop'
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:525:in `spawn_missing_workers'
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:536:in `maintain_worker_count'
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:294:in `join'
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
/bps_data/apps/chimiseng/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

---

**@@@@Edit START@@@@** 
add info about this..

in **/path/to/shared/bundle/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/activesupport/cache.rb:103-105**

```
102         def retrieve_store_class(store)
103           require "active_support/cache/#{store}"
104         rescue LoadError => e
105           raise "Could not find cache store adapter for #{store} (#{e})"
106         else
107           ActiveSupport::Cache.const_get(store.to_s.camelize)
108         end
```

**in active_support/cache/mem_cache_store.rb required**

```
1 begin                                                                         
2   require 'dalli'          # <- error !!                                               
3 rescue LoadError => e                                                                               
4   $stderr.puts "You don't have dalli installed in your application. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install"
5   raise e
6 end
```

### @@@@@Edit END@@@@@

and Here is **config/environment/production.rb and Gemfile**

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
...

# Use unicorn as the app server
gem 'unicorn'

gem 'dalli'

gem 'capistrano', "~> 2.15.0"
gem 'net-ssh', '~> 2.7.0'
gem 'rb-readline'
...
```

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
...
config.cache_classes = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store
...
```

**command 'bundle show' at APP_DIR (exists .bundle folder)**

```
...
* dalli (2.7.2)
...
```

**and ls /path/to/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems**

```
...
dalli-2.7.2
...
```

of course,, **APP_DIR/.bundle/config is defaults.**

```
---
BUNDLE_FROZEN: '1' 
BUNDLE_PATH: /path/to/shared/bundle
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: development:test
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'
```

and **/etc/memcached.conf**

```
-d
logfile /path/to/shared/log/memcached.log
-m 64
-p 11211
-u memcache
-l 127.0.0.1
```

**at my server, in APP_DIR command 'rails c -e production'**

```
Loading production environment (Rails 4.1.4)
irb(main):001:0> Rails.cache.stats
Dalli::Server#connect localhost:11211
localhost:11211 failed (count: 0) Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - send
=> {"localhost:11211"=>nil}
irb(main):002:0> 
irb(main):003:0* dc = Dalli::Client.new
=> #<Dalli::Client:0x007fa410d27d58 @servers=["127.0.0.1:11211"], @options={}, @ring=nil>
irb(main):004:0> 
irb(main):005:0* dc.stats
.......
irb(main):006:0> y _
---
127.0.0.1:11211:
  pid: '6657'
  uptime: '476'
  time: '1407552100'
  version: 1.4.13
  libevent: 2.0.16-stable
  pointer_size: '64'
  rusage_user: '0.000000'
  rusage_system: '0.032002'
  curr_connections: '5'
  total_connections: '7'
  connection_structures: '6'
  reserved_fds: '20'
  cmd_get: '0'
  cmd_set: '1'
  cmd_flush: '0'
  cmd_touch: '0'
  get_hits: '0'
  get_misses: '0'
  delete_misses: '0'
  delete_hits: '0'
  incr_misses: '0'
  incr_hits: '0'
  decr_misses: '0'
  decr_hits: '0'
  cas_misses: '0'
  cas_hits: '0'
  cas_badval: '0'
  touch_hits: '0'
  touch_misses: '0'
  auth_cmds: '0'
  auth_errors: '0'
  bytes_read: '160'
  bytes_written: '3709'
  limit_maxbytes: '67108864'
  accepting_conns: '1'
  listen_disabled_num: '0'
  threads: '4'
  conn_yields: '0'
  hash_power_level: '16'
  hash_bytes: '524288'
  hash_is_expanding: '0'
  expired_unfetched: '0'
  evicted_unfetched: '0'
  bytes: '73'
  curr_items: '1'
  total_items: '1'
  evictions: '0'
  reclaimed: '0'
 => nil
irb(main):007:0>
```

and **ps aux | grep memcached in my server**

```
memcache  6657  0.0  0.2 324248  2228 ?        Sl   11:33   0:00 /usr/bin/memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u memcache -l 127.0.0.1
```

and **/etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp restart**

```
reloaded OK
```

but.. server rails application not work.. 

**@@@Edit start (add info)@@@**

in my server , rails c -e production..

```
Loading production environment (Rails 4.1.4)
irb(main):001:0>require 'dalli'
=> false
irb(main):002:0>
```

this means.. dalli is already required. isn't it? 
hmm.. why cannot be required in active_support/cache/mem_cache_store.rb

**@@@Edit end @@@**

---

But it's **work very well at my local ubuntu**!!
local bundle installed list is same server (except for gem spring)..

```
Loading production environment (Rails 4.1.4)
irb(main):001:0> Rails.cache.stats
Dalli::Server#connect localhost:11211
=> {"localhost:11211"=>{"pid"=>"1976", "uptime"=>"13302", "time"=>"1407552926", "version"=>"1.4.13", "libevent"=>"2.0.16-stable", "pointer_size"=>"64", "rusage_user"=>"0.724000", "rusage_system"=>"0.296000", "curr_connections"=>"5", "total_connections"=>"10", "connection_structures"=>"7", "reserved_fds"=>"20", "cmd_get"=>"0", "cmd_set"=>"0", "cmd_flush"=>"1", "cmd_touch"=>"0", "get_hits"=>"0", "get_misses"=>"0", "delete_misses"=>"0", "delete_hits"=>"0", "incr_misses"=>"0", "incr_hits"=>"0", "decr_misses"=>"0", "decr_hits"=>"0", "cas_misses"=>"0", "cas_hits"=>"0", "cas_badval"=>"0", "touch_hits"=>"0", "touch_misses"=>"0", "auth_cmds"=>"0", "auth_errors"=>"0", "bytes_read"=>"244", "bytes_written"=>"5617", "limit_maxbytes"=>"67108864", "accepting_conns"=>"1", "listen_disabled_num"=>"0", "threads"=>"4", "conn_yields"=>"0", "hash_power_level"=>"16", "hash_bytes"=>"524288", "hash_is_expanding"=>"0", "expired_unfetched"=>"0", "evicted_unfetched"=>"0", "bytes"=>"0", "curr_items"=>"0", "total_items"=>"0", "evictions"=>"0", "reclaimed"=>"0"}}
```

What's the problem??
Please Help me T^T 
i am being crazy because of this..

Anyway.. Thank you for reading !

Comment: Hey did you find a fix for that ?

Comment: @CyrilDD No T^T. I've been using redis.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I added

```
 $stderr.puts "Error: #{e.message}"
```

above:

```
4   $stderr.puts "You don't have dalli installed in your application. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install"
```

Turns out I needed to have `connection_pool` installed. Once I installed that the error went away.